# How to monitor CPU, memory, and disk utilization during query execution in pig and hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, apache-pig, metrics

Same as the title. I am running a hadoop standalone cluster on my laptop. When I run a query, a map reduce job is created which can be seen on the web ui at ***localhost:8088***. However, it doesn't give complete information about the CPU, memory, and disk utilization during of that query execution, as shown below.

[image]

So, is there any way to monitor them. I am using linux and have installed hadoop(version 3.3.6), hive (version 3.1.3) and pig (version 0.17.0).

Comment: You can add promethus JMX Exporter to all hadoop processes